# Microsoft Grap API - Online meeting. Unable to create live event with public permission in Microsoft Teams

Tags: javascript, permissions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-live-meeting

I am trying to create a live event (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-live-events/what-are-teams-live-events) in Microsoft Teams using the Graph API with public permissions so that people can join the live event as guests.

Following the guidelines of documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-beta,
I cannot find a way to create an event with the desired configuration.

So far I have tried to use the following post configuration needed for the online meeting to be live and public:

```
{
    ....
    "isBroadcast": true,
    "autoAdmittedUsers": "everyone",
    "lobbyBypassSettings" : {
        "scope": "everyone",
        "isDialInBypassEnabled": true,
    }
};
```

Although I have set different values the returned response has the values set like this:

```
autoAdmittedUsers: "EveryoneInCompany"
lobbyBypassSettings: {scope: "organization", isDialInBypassEnabled: false}
outerMeetingAutoAdmittedUsers: "EveryoneInCompany"
```

Entering the event as an outside user prompts me to sign in and no join as guest option is available.

I am using JavaScript to send the requests and have tried using both the beta version of the API and 1.0 there isn't a change. Is the functionally of the Graph API not expected to work with live events and is it possible to create a live event with public permission in MS Teams using an API?

Comment: Don't set isBroadcast, in the payload. Rather use this `{
  "startDateTime":"2020-11-30T14:30:34.2444915-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2020-11-30T15:00:34.2464912-07:00",
  "subject":"User Token Meeting",
    "autoAdmittedUsers": "everyone",
    "lobbyBypassSettings" : {
        "scope": "everyone",
        "isDialInBypassEnabled": true
    }
}` and give a try.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: If I do not set "isBroadcast" to true, the meeting created is a standard one, not a live event. "Allowed Presenters" and "Auto AdmittedUser" were set to true, but like I said a normal online meeting was created not a live one.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0) could be useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no API to set up live event in teams.
Please look at [Set up live Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-live-events/set-up-for-teams-live-events) for an alternate way.

Answer (score 0):

remove all permission except below permission:

1. OnlineMeetings.Read
2. OnlineMeetingArtifact.Read.All

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heg0y.png)